# Cannot find module 'atptest' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angular-library

I have created an angular library using angular cli. I can use it locally but when I publish it to npm, I cannot use it in any angular application.

I install my published library using the following command and it installs without any problems:

```
npm i atptest
```

Here is how I want to import the module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AtptestModule } from 'atptest';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AtptestModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

However, it unfortunately does not work and throws the following error:

```
Cannot find module 'atptest' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

Here is the complete source code for the library:

> https://github.com/atoraby/atptest

Could anybody try to install this package and tell me what should I do to fix the problem? I guess there is a kind of configuration that I have missed. what does corresponding type declarations.ts mean?

Answer (score 1):

Check that your package has been installed alongside all other packages in node_modules directory (usually at the root of the project) and that you haven't created some nested `node_modules` directory hierarchy (by running npm install in any other than the root dir).

I gave it a try and installed the package. The actuall code is not pushed into your github repo yet, but by browsing into the `node_modules` folder I figured out that the actual location where your `AtptestModule` is located, is the following: `atptest/projects/atptest/src/lib/atptest.module` and this is related to the structure of your project.

[image]

Comment: I used `atptest/projects/atptest/src/lib/atptest.module`. Now I get the following error! 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵmod')